# Issue with language subfolders ranking in wrong country

Tags: seo, multilingual, internationalization

I have a multi language website with subfolders:
/uk/
/au/
/us/
/ca/

Unfortunately in the US, our UK subfolder is ranking causing users to go to the wrong version of the site. What's the best way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand two important concepts for internationalization.

For proper international targeting you need to use both hreflang attribute and google search console international targeting feature.

Using Hreflang attribute you can target people on their language basis.

Using Google search console international targeting feature you can target users in a specific country or location.

You can add upto 1000 different properties to search console

For example:- example.com/uk for United Kingdom
For example:- example.com/us for United States
For example:- example.com/au for Australia
For example:- example.com/ca for Canada

I think so this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the `hreflang` attribute on your pages as mentioned here:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?